# Error: A bytes-like object is required, not 'list'

Tags: django

I am developing a small project that aims to enable to the user to submit a zip file. The system should read the file, extract it and save its contents to the database.

I am having this error : a bytes-like object is required, not 'list' because I tried to use BytesIo. without it, the error said :" fpin.seek(0, 2)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'seek'"

My code looks like this

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('document[]')
with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(files), "r")as archive:
    for zippedFileName in archive.namelist():
        with archive.open(zippedFileName) as myfile:
            with io.BytesIO() as buf:
                buf.write(myfile.read())
                buf.seek(0)                                   
                file = File(buf, zippedFileName).decode('utf-8')
                rbe = UploadedFile.objects.create(document=file)                                 
                rbe.user= request.user
                rbe.save()                                   
                return render(request, 'uploader/index.html', {'files': files})
```

The error or traceback looks like this

Comment: Please post the complete error with trace back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Django, `request.FILES.getlist` returns a list of `UploadedFile` objects, each of which has a [`file`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File.file) attribute, a file-like object that you can pass directly to the `ZipFile` constructor.

Since your code apparently assumes that there is only one `UploadedFile` object in the list returned by `request.FILES.getlist`, you can unpack it like this:

```
uploaded_file, = request.FILES.getlist('document[]')
with zipfile.ZipFile(uploaded_file.file, "r") as archive:
    for zippedFileName in archive.namelist():
        ...

# you should return after the for loop, not within it
return render(request, 'uploader/index.html', {'files': [uploaded_file]})
```

Comment: @blhsing
I just found out that it saves the name of the file only without saving the actual file in the database. I can't find the file even in my project. Can you please tell me what I should change or add in my code?